# Autowiring issue with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class like below:

```
package com.company.data.render.model
@RestController
public class ControllerClass {

@Autowired
ApplicationPropertiesServiceImpl services;

@RequestMapping(value = "/node1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ParentNode getNode1() 
{


    Child node = new Child();
    List<Map<String, Object>> properties properties = services.getData("A",xxx);
    node.addtree();
    node.setProperties(properties);
    return node;
}
 }   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.company.data.service;
@Component
public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(String type,String name) 
{
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            String sql = "select * from data.data_properties(?)";
            List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,host);
            return rows;
        }else if(properties.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            String sql = "select * from data.application_properties(?)";
            List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,host);
            return rows;
        }

}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package com.company.data.render.model;

@Component
public class Child {

@Autowired
ApplicationPropertiesServiceImpl services;


public void addtree()
{
List<Map<String, Object>> properties=services.getData("B", "xxy");

}
}
```

How can I access the **getdata()** function in **Child** class.I am getting null pointer exception for **service**  object though I have **autowired** the **ApplicationPropertiesServiceImpl**

Comment: You misspelled the annotation it should be `@Autowired`. However it is a bad idea to wire a controller into another component. It would be better if you extract the common code into a separate `@Service` bean and the reference that bean from the controller and your `Child` class. Of course you also have to have setup the application context correctly and initialized it.

Comment: It's better you to separate the logic, current your controller is doing too much stuff. I would suggest you to make 2 classes: a service and a DAO (repository). The repository will give you the result of the db. And the service will have the DAO object + some business. Both controllers will have the service autowired.

Comment: @korogue --evenif i create a seperate class..How will i get the same service object in both the class??

Comment: use the annotation @Autowired

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are going to have 2 Controllers.

Clearly your controller is doing too much. And it's not a good idea to inject a controller into another controller.

I suggest you to make a Service and a Repository:

The model is receiving to much data from the Controller so I suggest to create a class to make it more clear, because return a Map is too abstract and make the code hard to read.

```
public class CarProperties {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String color;
    //setters and gettters
    ....
}
```

Service:

```
public interface CarPropertiesService {
   public List<CarProperties> findAll(String type);
}

@Service("CarPropertiesService")
public class CarPropertiesServiceImpl implements CarPropertiesService {
   @Autowired
   private CarPropertiesDAO carPropertiesDAO;

   public List<CarProperties> findAll(String type) {
      List<CarProperties> result = new ArrayList<>();
      if ("XXX".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
         List<Map<String, Object>> carPropertiesList = carPropertiesDAO.findAll();
         for(Map<String, Object> carProperties : carPropertiesList) {
            result.add(getCarPropertiesInstance(carProperties));
         }

      }
      return result;
   }

   private CarProperties getCarPropertiesInstance(Map<String, Object> properties) {
      CarProperties instance = new CarProperties();
      instance.setId(properties.get("id"));
      instance.setName(properties.get("name"));
      ...
      return instance;
   }
}
```

DAO:

```
public interface CarPropertiesDAO {
   public List<Map<String, Object>> findAll();
}

@Repository("CarPropertiesDAO")
public class CarPropertiesDAOImpl implements CarPropertiesDAO {
   ...
   public List<Map<String, Object>> findAll() {
      String sql = "select * from data.car_properties(?)";
      return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,host);
   }
}
```

and finally your controllers would make usage of the service:

```
@RestController
public class ControllerClass {
    @Autowired
    private CarPropertiesService carPropertiesService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/node1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ParentNode getNode1() 
    {
       List<CarProperties> properties = carPropertiesService.findAllByType("XXX");
       return properties;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/prop/{type}/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<CarProperties> getData(@PathVariable String type,@PathVariable String name) 
   {
      List<CarProperties> rows = carPropertiesService.findAllByType(type);    
      ...
   }
}

@Controller
public class Controller2 {
   @Autowired
   CarPropertiesService carPropertiesService;


   public void addtree(){
      List<CarProperties> rows = carPropertiesService.findAllByType("XXX");
   }
}
```

Resuming: Controllers should not worry about the business, but only returning the data. Service should be where the business is, like calculations, data exchange, etc... The DAO class you can clearly see it is used to DB actions. Also keep in mind the access to the DAO objects should be in Services/Facedes, using it in the Controller recommended. So using this structure your code would became more reusable and easy to maintain.

Comment: But what is necessaty of two dao and impl classes...isnt it confusing littilbit

Comment: Not really, one is the interface and the other the class. You can reuse the interface for different classes.

Comment: This solution is not going to fit into my problem..anyways thanks Becoz this is not  a table i am querying..it is a function i am executing through the query..

Comment: then the function should be in the service

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this :-

```
@Component
@ComponentScan(basePackages="<provide your base pkg where it will scan for the component ControllerClass>")
@ConditionalOnBean(ControllerClass.class)
public class Child {
  @Autowired(required=true)
  private ControllerClass controllerClass;

  public void addtree(){
    controllerClass.getData("XXX",xxx)
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls check my updated suggestion above to include annotation @ComponentScan.

Comment: This is exactly what i have mentioned in the project..No other configuration

Comment: Is your project a spring boot project ??

Comment: Yes..It is a spring boot project

Comment: I just imported your code to a spring boot project and its working fine. No change is needed to your code for autowiring or anything and Spring boot app automatically enables the @ComponentScan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91591/discussion-between-aman-and-avis).